# How to ignore backup files (~) when running grep?

Tags: grep, backup

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `grep` can be used to find strings in files. But I'm not interested in backup files (those whose name ends with a `~`).

How should I ignore those files when using the `grep` command?

Comment: Is this a question about how to use grep (if you do `C-h i` and navigate to coreutils then grep it should help) or how to use `M-x grep` in emacs?

Comment: Considering that you manually provide arguments to `grep`, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emacs provide `lgrep` and `rgrep` as convenient interfaces for `grep`. These commands may invoke `grep` on the command line with `grep` options systematically (see also the [GNU Emacs Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html#Grep-Searching)). More specifically, the *user option* `grep-find-ignored-files` (discovered after searching in the source code and in the integrated documentation) may be set to ignore some files.

```
M-x customize-variable
Customize variable: grep-find-ignored-files
```

However, the variable `grep-find-ignored-files` already contains the value `*~` in my default setting so `lgrep` and `rgrep` ignore backup files.

In my GNU environment, the variable allows to add several `--exclude=` options on the command line to `grep` when a user invokes `lgrep` dynamically.

**Note:** The user may modify the settings globally by customizing the group `grep` (`customize-group`).

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the pattern match to exclude file with names ending in `~` via `[^~]`.  When M-x grep prompts you for the grep command, use something like:

```
grep match-text ./path/*[^~]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put your backup files somewhere else. When you do a grep emacs will ask for the root directory for the search, defaulting to the current directory. You could specify a directory for the backup files that is outside the places you usually search. You can do this by setting backup-directory-alist.

```
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.saves")))
```

Full details are here:
[How do I control how Emacs makes backup files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151946/1671119)